# How to create a formula in Excel that will search for a value in one column (external sheet) and another value in another column (same ext sheet)

Tags: excel, search, find, formula, vlookup

I have two Excel sheets and need to see if items in one of them (smaller) are already included at the other.

Problem: columns are not the same. Some are, but not all, and indexed items are duplicated (customers).

I´d like to use (for example) "customer" and "invoice #" as index, because these items are in both sheets, and search for "invoice number" and "amount" in sheet 02, and return to sheet 01, to compare "amount".

Example:

**Sheet 1**

| Customer | Invoice | Amount | Amount for sheet2 | Invoice Confirmation | Amount confirmation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 45 | $345 | $3450 | match | **not match** |
| Peter | 139 | $265 | $2.65 | match | **not match** |
| Paul | 425 | $345 | $345 | match | **match** |
| Peter | 279 | $5.265 | $5.265.000 | match | **not match** |

*1.000 lines*

**Sheet 2**

| Customer | Invoice | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 45 | $3450 |
| Peter | 139 | $2.65 |
| Paul | 425 | $345 |
| Cesar | 478 | $7.345 |
| Peter | 279 | $5.265.000 |

*234k lines*

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try, using **INDEX & MATCH** Function or if you are using O365 then use **XLOOKUP** Function with **Boolean** Logic

• Formula used in cell **D3** - 2 ways,

**Approach_One** --> Confirm enter `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` instead of just `ENTER` after entering the formula, since its an array formula

```
=INDEX($C$10:$C$14,MATCH(1,(A3=$A$10:$A$14)*(B3=$B$10:$B$14),0))
```

**Approach_Two**

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A3=$A$10:$A$14)*(B3=$B$10:$B$14),$C$10:$C$14)
```

• Formula used in cell **E3** - 2 ways,

**Approach_One**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(A3=$A$10:$A$14)*(B3=$B$10:$B$14),0)),"Match","Not Match")
```

**Approach_Two**

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(1,(A3=$A$10:$A$14)*(B3=$B$10:$B$14),$B$10:$B$14)=B3,"Match","Not Match")
```

• Formula used in cell **F3** - 2 ways,

**Approach_One**

```
=IF(D3=C3,"Match","Not Match")
```

**Approach_Two**

```
=(D3=C3)*1
```

And Custom Format as --> Select the range --> Press `CTRL` + `1` --> Format cells Dialog --> Number Tab --> Category --> Custom --> Type the below -->

```
[=1]"Match";[=0]"Not Match";
```

Using of Boolean Logic is a more flexible approach since the syntax can be adjusted to use other logical operators and other functions as needed.

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]